# Sqrt function not working

Tags: c, sqrt, libm

So I'm trying to make a program that calculates the quadratic formula, but when I try to compile the code, I get the following:"undefined reference to sqrt"
But I tried defining sqrt via math.h and 2 other times in the code.
I have attached my code
Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double sqrt(double);

int main (void) {
  double sqrt(double);
  int a,b,c;
  double discriminant,squarerootofdis,root1, root2;
  printf("Please enter the coefficient of x^2:");
  scanf("%d",&a);
  printf("Please enter the coefficient of x:");
  scanf("%d",&b);
  printf("Please enter the integer value of the ploynomial:");
  scanf("%d",&c);
  if (a==0 && b==0)
    {printf("This case is extremely degenerate");}
  else if (a==0 && b!=0)
    {root1=-c/b;
      printf("Degenerate     one real root: %lf\n",root1);}
  else{
    discriminant = ((b*b)-(4*a*c)); 
    squarerootofdis = sqrt(discriminant);
    root1 = (squarerootofdis-b)/(2*a);
    root2 = (-squarerootofdis-b)/(2*a);
    if (discriminant>0)
      printf("Two real roots: %lf\n %lf\n", root1, root2);
    else if (discriminant == 0)
      printf("Degenerate     one real root: %lf\n",root1);
    else if (discriminant<0)
      printf("Two complex roots: %lf\n %lf\n", root1, root2);
  }
}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Emacs?

Comment: I made the code in emacs

Comment: so nothing, I'm removing the `emacs` tag

Comment: ok, sorry about that, I'm new to this site and C

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, be sure to read the FAQ.

Comment: why are there 2 declarations of sqrt when it was in math.h?

Answer (score 2):

To use the `sqrt` function (or any function defined in `math.h`), you'll have to link the `m` library:

```
~$ gcc -lm yourcode.c -o program
```

Comment: is that -onem or -letterlm or -captialim?

Comment: It's the `-l` (that is lowercase L) option of `gcc` (read the manpage), with the parameter `m`. This will make `gcc` link the `libm` library dynamically with your program. Check also this page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker

Answer (score 1):

Did you compile with `-lm` linked?

Header file will provide the *decalration* to the `sqrt()` function. To have the *definition*, you need to link with the `math` library consisting of the function definition.

Example:

```
gcc test.c -o output -lm
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below command

gcc test.c `-lmath`